# Postback via <h:commandLink> to same page causes duplicate entries in browser history

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

With plain Jsf postback to same page (with return null in method) from commandLink, I am ending up with two duplicate entries in browser history. One entry with url with ending # and one with url without ending #. Please help if you have any idea why this could happen and advice avoiding it.

I am assuming this is not a standard behavior with JSF postback request. Please help confirming it.

Also please suggest where I could be going wrong. I am using Myfaces 2.1

Also any pointer to debug this scenario is very much appreciated.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out my issue. As I had expected, it is not the issue with JSF as such. I have  commandLinks with onclick method, for disabling all the hyperLink controls to prevent repeated submits. That method is also setting location.href = "#" before returning true, and this was the cause of double entries in browser back history. Posting the answer, hoping it will help others with same scenarios. Thanks all for viewing this question.